# How to prevent access to an image folder in PHP with sessions?

Tags: php, image, security, session

I have a folder named "images" and subfolders named from their owner's username.

How can I give access to the content of a folder to its owner using sessions?

Should I use something like this?

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
  readfile('images/username/randomlygeneratedimagename.png');
} else {
  die();
}
```

However if someone finds the source of the image he can directly access it without being logged in...

And more generally, is it necessary to have such security? If the owner doesn't share his images no one could guess the filename and access it...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got the right solution. Just make sure you store the assets where they're not publicly accessible. If the images are readable by your PHP script then it can serve them using your code - the assets don't actually have to be accessibly to download directly for it to work.

One other point, if you want a slightly more performant solution, consider using an X-SendFile header approach ([mod_xsendfile for Apache](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), or use the built in functionality of lighttpd or nginx). This let's you tell Apache what file to serve without having to pass through the actual data. It's actually very easy to set up (easier than your approach, IMO) and is particularly good for serving large files, or scaling up volume considerably.

Comment: I don't understand the assets part though, if I protect the assets folder with a .htaccess file, how can my PHP script access the images?
Allowing localhost is enough?

Comment: `.htaccess` tells Apache how to serve the image, it does *not* define any file system priveledges, so if PHP has permission to read the file it can do so, regardless of what .htaccess says. Note that the assets don't have to be in your web root at all. They could be in some other more secure location if you wanted to do that too.